# How do I access MultiValue data from U2 Toolkit for .NET?

Tags: .net, u2, unidata, u2netdk

I am getting the following message when trying to select * from the U2 data files.

`[U2][UCINET][UNIDATA]:Multi-value or multi-subvalue are not supported in this version\r\n"`

Is there a version that does not get this error, if I select only one field I do not get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set property "FirstNormalForm=false"  in U2ConnectionStringBuilder Class. For example:

```
            U2ConnectionStringBuilder conn_str = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
            conn_str.UserID = "user";
            conn_str.Password = "pass";
            conn_str.Server = "localhost";
            conn_str.Database = "XDEMO";
            conn_str.ServerType = "UNIVERSE";
            conn_str.FirstNormalForm = false;

            U2Connection con = new U2Connection();
            con.ConnectionString = conn_str.ToString();
            con.Open();
            .......
```

For UniVerse Database:
SQL Statement : SELECT FNAME,PRICE,BUY_DATE FROM UNNEST CUSTOMER ON ORDERS
(PRICE and BUY_DATE are multi-valued attributes)

For UniData Database:
SQL Statement : SELECT * FROM STUDENT UNNEST NL_ALL CGA
(FNAME,...,SEMESTER  are multi-valued attributes)